# Is it possible to display a React component from another library using innerHTML?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to render a react component inside innerHTML. So i am trying to create a plugin for an application and i want to display a react component i get from another library of mine.

```
import React from 'react';

import { PanelProps } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimpleOptions } from 'types';
import { Header } from 'someLibrary';

interface Props extends PanelProps<SimpleOptions> {}

let header = document.createElement('div');

header.innerHTML = `<Header />`;

export const SimplePanel: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  
  let mainView = document.querySelector('.main-view');

  (mainView as HTMLElement).prepend(header);


  return (
    <div>
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `'<Header />'` is just a string.  You need something more like `header.innerHTML = Header();` where you call your function.

Comment: You could render the component normally then get its HTML content from the DOM and copy that over to the innerHTML of the element you want, but it's a hack and it probably won't end up working very well. Why not just render the component normally?